# Monte-carlo methods in graphics

Tags: javascript, graphics, random, montecarlo

I was reading through [this interesting post](http://www.romancortes.com/blog/1k-rose/) about using JavaScript to generate an image of a rose. However, I'm a bit confused, as [this article](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/02/a-rose-by-any-other-name-might-smell-as-sweet-but-it-would-probably-be-larger) claims that the author used monte carlo methods to reduce the code size.

It's my understanding that the author was using monte carlo methods to do something like GIF interlacing, so that the image would appear to load more quickly. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Monte-Carlo (MC) method used by the author has nothing to do with the resulting image file type, it has everything to do with how the image was generated in the first place. Since the point of JS1K is to write *compact* code, the author defines the rose by mathematical forms that are to be filled in with tiny dots (so they look like a solid image) by a basic render.

How do you fill those forms in? One method is to sample the surface *uniformly*, that is over a set interval, place a dot. As @Jordan quoted, it will work if and only if the interval is set correctly. Make it to small it takes to long; make it to large, the image is patchwork. However you can bypass the whole problem by sampling over the surface *randomly*. This is where the MC method comes in.

I've seen this confusion over MC before, since it is often thought of as a tool for numerical simulation. While widely used as such, the core idea is to randomly sample an interval with a bias that weights each step accordingly (dependent on the problem). For example, a physics simulation might have a weight of e^(-E/kT), whereas a numerical integrator might use a weight proportional to the derivative at the sample point. The [wikipeida entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) (and the refs. therein) are a good starting place for a more detail.

**You can think of the complete rose as a function that is fully computed. As the MC algorithm runs, it samples this function while it converges onto the correct answer.**

Comment: So the real reason why the code is small is becuase the image is in the form of a function. The randomness is just to get around the interval problem.

Comment: @pepsi Correct. MC (while elegantly used here) is simply a means to an end. If he didn't use it, he would have to define the sample intervals for each form, wasting space.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I still think the Wired/WebMonkey article is misleading though :)

Answer (score 1):

The author writes in the article that he uses Monte Carlo sampling to overcome the limitations of interval based sampling because the latter "requires the setting of a proper interval for each surface. If the interval is big, it render fast but it can end with holes in the surface that has not been filled. On the other hand, if the interval is too little, the time for rendering increments up to prohibitive quantities." I believe that the WebMonkey article's conclusion re: code size is incorrect.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. However, at the top of the author's article he writes regarding monte carlo methods, "In the case of the rose, it was very useful for code size optimization."